# Filled circle progress bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Does anyone know how to do filled circle progress bar like on a picture?

[image: Picture:]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, haven't tried anything :)

Comment: It is necessary to show your effort while asking question including your code-snippet, try my post it will work as you expected, play with value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `CustomPainter`

```dart
class CirclePaint extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;

  CirclePaint(this.value);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final area = Rect.fromCircle(
        center: size.center(Offset.zero), radius: size.width / 2);

    canvas.drawArc(
        area, -pi / 2, 2 * pi * value, true, Paint()..color = Colors.amber);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

And play with this widget and change the color you like to have.

```dart
  double value = .4;
  final size = 200.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
              value: value,
              onChanged: (v) {
                setState(() {
                  value = v;
                });
              },
            ),
            Container(
              width: size,
              height: size,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 4,
                ),
              ),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: CirclePaint(value),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

[image]

Find more about [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

With Listenable repaint as  pskink mentioned on comment

```dart
class Psf extends StatelessWidget {
  const Psf({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ValueNotifier<double> value = ValueNotifier(.3);

    const size = 200.0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
              value: value.value,
              onChanged: (v) {
                value.value = v;
              },
            ),
            Container(
              width: size,
              height: size,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 4,
                ),
              ),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: CirclePaint(value),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CirclePaint extends CustomPainter {
  final ValueNotifier<double> value;

  CirclePaint(this.value) : super(repaint: value);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final area = Rect.fromCircle(
        center: size.center(Offset.zero), radius: size.width / 2);

    canvas.drawArc(area, -pi / 2, 2 * pi * value.value, true,
        Paint()..color = Colors.amber);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CirclePaint oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.value != value;
}
```

With custom decoration as @pskink included, you need to use some custom snippet for this, check them [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/91b658f23c8d2f6fa6c73ae5c29173b2#file-decoration_misc-dart-L284)

```dart
Container(
  width: size,
  height: size,
  decoration: AnimatedDecoration(
    listenable: value,
    onPaintFrame: (canvas, bounds, double v) {
      canvas.drawArc(bounds, -pi / 2, 2 * pi * v, true,
          Paint()..color = Colors.amber);
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: btw, you can avoid calling `setState` (and rebuilding the entire widget tree) if you use `repaint` parameter in `CustomPainter` constructor

Comment: Do you mean `bool shouldRepaint(covariant CirclePaint oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.value!=value;` Also I’ve a slider here

Comment: no, i mean `Listenable? repaint` used in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/CustomPainter.html

Comment: also you can use [AnimatedDecoration](https://gist.github.com/pskink/91b658f23c8d2f6fa6c73ae5c29173b2#file-decoration_misc-dart-L426) so you don't need any `CustomPaint` widget and instead you can use any `Container` or `DecoratedBox` widgets